# gfortran: debian 6.0.8 - compilation fails

Tags: linux, fortran90

I am trying to use several programs for watershed generation, genericaly called TOPAZ, from

ftp://solar1.msa-oxford.ars.usda.gov/pub/outgoing/TOPAZ/TOPAZ312/Ascii/

the source code is available, so everybody can try

The code is not mine, and i thank publicly here to the authors for their work.

Machine for development is debian 6.0.8, kernel  2.6.32-5-amd64

The source code of all programs conforms strictly to FORTRAN 90 standards, acording to the documentation.

installed gfortran, and when compiling i get

---

```
root@geo:/usr/src/topaz.src/tmp# gfortran -v DEDNM.F90
Driving: gfortran -v DEDNM.F90 -lgfortranbegin -lgfortran -lm -shared-libgcc
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.4.5-8' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.4/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.4 --enable-shared --enable-multiarch --enable-linker-build-id --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.4 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --with-arch-32=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/f951 DEDNM.F90 -cpp /tmp/ccLDYiVO.f90 -quiet -v DEDNM.F90 -quiet -dumpbase DEDNM.F90 -mtune=generic -auxbase DEDNM -version -fintrinsic-modules-path /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/finclude -o /tmp/ccy4DOzn.s
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/finclude
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU Fortran (Debian 4.4.5-8) version 4.4.5 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.4.5, GMP version 4.3.2, MPFR version 3.0.0-p3.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=55 --param ggc-min-heapsize=47475
DEDNM.F90:12415.1:

\x1A
 1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
```

---

i get a similar error on compiling the other programs,

the source is ANSI Standard Fortran90, acording to documentation

i don't know much of fortran, but i would like to use a linux machine rather than going back to windows, and so need to compile the programs instead of using precompliled ones for win95

many thanks
André

Comment: So do some diagnosis.  What does file `DEDNM.F90` contain at line `12415`, in particular in column `1` of that line ?

Comment: i had already looked to that line, and it had very comon code.
however, since you sad your coment, i tried to erase the first CHAR of thar line and re-wrote it.
and now it compiles just file.
As to the other files, i went to the line of the error and it wal always the end of file. I erase it, and saved. 
And know they all compile fine.

I must have bin a problem with opening the source files with ms-dos editors and linux/unix editors, that caused one worng char meaning end-of-file....

Many thanks,
simple problems have simple solutions

Comment: Not only do simple problems have simple solutions but compiler error messages are worthy of serious attention.